# Prevent crash of a C++ app when C# causes exceptions

Tags: c#, c++

I'm modding an old game written by my father in early 2000's.

I've injected my `ModCore.dll` written in C# into the game, then activated it using `ModInitializer.dll` written in C++ CLI.

In general, it works - it pops a console as it should, allows me to directly read/write memory, execute functions and override some assembly code.

The issue I'm having is that it crashes whenever I'm trying to read protected memory because I've accidentally miscalculated the offset or whenever I'm trying to call a method with wrong param types.

My question is: how can I prevent exceptions of an already compiled C++ app from crashing it - exceptions caused by for example: injected C# library attempting to read protected memory.

**Edit:** Point of note - I am handling all the C# exceptions in my module by wrapping them in try/catch, it doesn't sadly cover exceptions from the C++ app itself.

Comment: wrap the calls to the failing functions in try/catch?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @AlanBirtles I did - the app crashes not because of C# exceptions, but because of C++ exceptions.

Comment: @HansPassant That worked well, thanks! - if you could just post it as an answer, I could mark it as the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you can't catch memory access violations in C++. C++ does not throw a catchable exception when it happens, because checking correctness would incur a significant performance penalty.

You'll need to make sure your offsets are calculated correctly.

Comment: The solution provided in comments of the question seems to work.
Which means your answer is not an answer at all.

Comment: @JCode: It certainly is an answer, but an incorrect one in your case. What you have isn't memory access violations apparently.